# Using model in Laravel resource controller does not work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When using a resource controller I want to check a certain id. I'm using this id in every function in the resource controller so I want to load this only once in the constructor. But when using Eloquent models I keep receiving the error:

Call to a member function connection() on null

This is my code, how can i fix this?

```
namespace NameSpaceCompany\Utility\Controller;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use NameSpaceCompany\Utility\Model\Entity;

class StatusController extends Controller
{
    public $entity = "Status";

    public $entityModel = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entityModel = Entity::where('entity_name',$this->entity)->first();

        dd($this->entityModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: And stack-trace?

Comment: Looks like your database settings are off. Have you been able to communicate with your database before this heppened? And please provide a stacktrace as @Top-Master requested.

Comment: ive managed to fix it via a Helper class:

```$this->entity = app('EntityHelper')->getEntity(__CLASS__);```

and in the app service provider:

```$this->app->singleton('EntityHelper', function () {
            $entities = Entity::all();
            return new EntityHelper($entities);
        });```

Answer (score 0):

ive managed to fix it via a Helper class:

`$this->entity = app('EntityHelper')->getEntity(__CLASS__);`

and in the app service provider:

```
$this->app->singleton('EntityHelper', function () {
    $entities = Entity::all();
    return new EntityHelper($entities);
});
```